# How can I merge two branches without losing any files?

Tags: git, merge

I have two branches with the following files in there:

**branch a:**

```
file_a
file_b
file_c
```

**branch b:**

```
file_a
file_d
file_e
```

I want to merge them, so that I get both files from **a** and **b** (and files that exist in both should normally be merged)! is that possbile?

Comment: Why don't you simply get both branches and merge them manually?

Comment: clone two times and copy and add?

Comment: You migt want to ask this over on StackOverflow... programmers over there might know more about this stuff.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

this might help: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

in your case you would do the following:

- `git checkout a` (you will switch to branch a)
- `git merge b` (this will merge all changes from branch b into branch a)
- `git commit -a` (this will commit your changes)

take a look at above link to get the full picture.